# CSS: How do I trigger a hover on each cell of a table if their table header is hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assuming I have different kinds of classes in my table cells to handle a `hover`, how do I trigger all of these `hover` events when their corresponding header is hovered over?

Comment: Why not just add classes to these cells, and that class do `hover` effect?

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Comment: Please can you add some code and/or a JS Fiddle demonstrating what you have tried so far.

Comment: .header-class:hover .table-class:hover ?

Comment: I was looking for something like this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/g0u2qtxo/2/

Snippet:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#iTable td").hover(function () {
    alert("cell hover");
});

$("#iHead").hover(function () {
    alert("header hover");
    $("#iTable td").mouseenter();
});
```

});

Dependency: use jquery...

Answer (score 0):

CSS effects to change style of rows on hover and JavaScript to handle click event.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5apnLjqt/

HTML:

```
<tr class="clickable" onclick="nav('http://www.google.com');">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
tr.clickable:hover td { 
    background: #FFFF00; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function nav (url) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```